# Removing Special Characters / Punctuation for the end of a Python List of URL's

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am writing a Python code to extract all the URLs from an input file, having content or text from Twitter (Tweets). However, while doing so I realized that several URLs that were extracted in the python list had 'special characters' or 'Punctuation' towards the end, because of which I could not further parse through them to get the base URL link. My Question is: 'How do I identify & remove special characters from the end of every URL in my list' ?

Current Output:

```
['https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u'', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u@#', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u"']
```

Desired Output:

```
['https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u']
```

You would appreciate that not all elements in the 'Current Output' list have special characters / punctuation towards the end. The task is to identify & remove characters / punctuation only from the list elements who have them.

I am using the following Regex to extract twitter URLs from the Tweet Text: `lst = re.findall('(http.?://[^\s]+)', text)`
Can I remove the special characters / punctuation towards the end of the URL, in this step itself ?

Full Code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from socket import timeout
import ssl
import re
import csv

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

count = 0
file = "Test.CSV"
with open(file,'r', encoding='utf-8') as f, open('output_themes_1.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as ofile:
    next(f)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    fir = 'S.No.', 'Article_Id', 'Validity', 'Content', 'Geography', 'URL'
    writer.writerow(fir)
    for line in reader:
        count = count+1
        text = line[5]
        lst = re.findall('(http.?://[^\s]+)', text)
        if not lst:
            x = count, line[0], 'Empty List', text, line[8], line[6]
            print (x)
            writer.writerow(x)
        else:
            try:
                for url in lst:
                    try:
                        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx, timeout=60).read()
                        #html = urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.parse.quote(url, errors='ignore'), context=ctx).read()
                        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
                        title = soup.title.string
                        str_title = str (title)
                        if 'Twitter' in str_title:
                            if len(lst) > 1: break
                            else: continue
                        else:
                            y = count, line[0], 'Parsed', str_title, line[8], url
                            print (y)
                            writer.writerow(y)
                    except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
                        b_url = url.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
                        n_url = b_url.decode("utf-8")
                        try:
                            html = urllib.request.urlopen(n_url, context=ctx, timeout=90).read()
                            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
                            title = soup.title.string
                            str_title = str (title)
                            if 'Twitter' in str_title:
                                if len(lst) > 1: break
                                else: continue
                            else:
                                z = count, line[0], 'Parsed_2', str_title, line[8], url
                                print (z)
                                writer.writerow(z)
                        except Exception as e:
                            a = count, line[0], str(e), text, line[8], url
                            print (a)
                            writer.writerow(a)
            except Exception as e:
                b = count, line[0], str(e), text, line[8], url
                print (b)
                writer.writerow(b)
print ('Total Rows Analyzed:', count)
```

Comment: Define a list of special characters then remove the last character if it is in your list and start again

Comment: Are the special characters always at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the special characters occur at the end of the string you may use:

```
mydata = ['https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u', "https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u'", 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u@#', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u"']
mydata = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$','',item) for item in mydata]
print(mydata)
```

Prints:

```
['https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u']
```

Comment: Sorry for asking a naive question, but how does this work with my code scenario below:

Comment: 1. lst = re.findall('(http.?://[^\s]+)', text)
2. lst = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$','',item) for item in lst] . This doesn't seem to work. After I have a list from Step 1., I should look at removing special characters / punctuation from step 2.

Comment: In one of the row i am getting the URL: https://twitter.com/va0JsrIavm', which ofcourse can't be parsed further because of the ' at the end of the URL.

Comment: Can you share the output of the first step? Is it `['https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u'', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u@#', 'https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u"']` ? Is the first step even needed?

Comment: the output would be something like:

Comment: 319 7.35E+11 HTTP Error 404: Not Found '@MarriottRewards 14 #RewardsPoints https://twitter.com/va0JsrIavm' Unknown https://twitter.com/va0JsrIavm'
496 7.35E+11 Parsed "
Connect and Start Earning
| Chirpify
" United States https://twitter.com/GVNyqWEu5u
Now you'd note for the URL alongside row 319 is https://twitter.com/va0JsrIavm', now since it has a punctuation at the end, the code is unable to parse the URL & gives the 404 error. Therefore, comes my question, "how do I Identify & Remove Special Characters / Punctuation for the end of a Python List of URL's". Hope this is more clear now.

Comment: Please note that its "t.co" instead of "twitter.com" in all the twiiter links.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is. My code will remove the `'` at the end of `twitter.com/va0JsrIavm'` .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is called urls:

```
def remove_special_chars(url, char_list=None):
    if char_list is None:
        # Build your own default list here
        char_list = ['#', '%']
    for character in char_list:
        if url.endswith(character):
            return remove_special_chars(url[:-1], char_list)
    return url

urls = [remove_special_chars(url) for url in urls]
```

If you want to get rid of a special set of characters just change either the default value or pass a proper list as an argument

Comment: Added the full code, please check the problem now. Also note that, i am facing most of my problems with " & ', how do you precisely handle them ?

Comment: In one of the row i am getting the URL: https://twitter.com/va0JsrIavm', which ofcourse can't be parsed further because of the ' at the end of the URL.

Comment: add those characters in char_list, in the case of ' add it as "'" (with double quotes), the function will keep on trimming from the right until there is no special character at the end of the url.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
lst = [re.sub('[=" ]$', '', i) for i in re.findall('(http.?://[^\s]+)', text)]
```

You can just add more characters that you want to replace in your sub according to your requirements

Comment: Sadly. This Doesn't seem to work. Would you need more info. to de-bug ?

Comment: In one of the row i am getting the URL: https://twitter.com/va0JsrIavm', which ofcourse can't be parsed further because of the ' at the end of the URL.